# Refresh page from IE developer tools

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

Is it possible via keyboard shortcut to reload the page from within internet explorer's developer tools? This is possible with firebug: ctrl+r reloads the page automatically. While ctrl+r clears the browser cache for IE.

I would like to clear the cache and refresh the page via keyboard shortcuts.

**TLDR**

From within Developer Tools in IE, can you reload the page via keyboard shortcut?

**UPDATE**

Added in a feature request to microsoft, the link can be found:
[here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811214/refresh-page-from-inside-ie-developer-tools)

Comment: I just click on page(make focus) and reload it by ctrl-r.

Comment: I realize this, I was just wondering if it was possible within developer tools, 1 less action :)

Comment: no not at this time. put in a feature request on http://connect.Microsoft.com. I will vote for it :) Add a link to a comment here.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811214/refresh-page-from-inside-ie-developer-tools